# Using Fourier transform solve the integral equation below:

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$\int_{0}^\infty y(x)cos(\omega x)dx$=\begin{Bmatrix}\omega+2, &0\le\omega\le3 \newline 0, &\omega>3  \end{Bmatrix}

I don't know from where i start to solve? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Given the bounds, it might make more sense to use the laplace transform

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use inverse Fourier transform
$$
y(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^3 (\omega+2)\cos(\omega x)d\omega
$$
Calculation using Wolfram Alpha gives
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E3+%28%5Comega%2B2%29%5Ccos%28%5Comega+x%29d%5Comega